# Unable to install intl extension for php

Tags: php, command-line-interface, pear, intl

I have been trying to install the `intl` extension for php on my command line interface. But have ran into some difficulties.

When I run :

```
sudo pecl install intl
```

I get the following error :

```
fatal error: 'ext/standard/php_smart_str.h' file not found
#include <ext/standard/php_smart_str.h>
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Don't install anything via PECL that you can install via your package mamanger.

Comment: Did you solve this problem ? By the way `brew install intl` is not working.